# router dhcp config for pxe boot

Tags: pxe, dnsmasq, dhcp-server

I want to set up pxe/tftp server in my network. 
I already have a dhcp server on my isp router wich has dhcp option 60 and dhcp option 240.
I nee to know if can i set it up in order to lease pxe info (tftp server and boot) or i need to set up a brand new dhcp with dnsmasq.
In case i need to set up a new dhcp server i need to know if both can be up at time or i must deactivate the older one.
So i need to know if the new one can be configured ony for pxe lease info and maintain the original one as long as it has be working until now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options

1. Setting your ISP router as a PXE server by adding options 66 & 67 or the fields file and next_server if available
2. Leaving the ISP DHCP server untouched and use an additional DHCP server like i.e. dnsmask set as **proxyDHCP**. In this case your ISP DHCP will only provide IP information to every booting device while the proxyDHCP will provide PXE information "only" to booting PXE clients.

Some ISP routers are not really flexible for setting up a PXE environment then option 2 is always your best choice.

By all means avoid MAC filters and the like they are a mess and will lead you to hard to troubleshoot scenarios.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. I really need proxyDHCP config. Any idea about some tutorial to set up one proxydhcp for pxe?

Comment: The quick and easy way to proxyDHCP is Serva (I'm related to Serva development). If you prefer dnsmask a proxyDHCP how-to can be found here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/ProxyDHCP

Answer (score -1):

In order to use PXE, you must set option 66 (TFTP Boot Server Address) and option 67 (Bootfile name). If you are not able to configure it in current DHCP server, you will have to use another DHCP server. Dnsmasq can act as DHCP/BOOTP and TFTP server.

Comment: Thanks but i the main problem i need to solve is about config The second dhcp server only for pxe without affecting The first one that is not supporting dnsmasq options.

Comment: You can't do PXE without configure the main DHCP server. Only if you ignore the MAC addresses that yo want to use PXE on the first one and respond only on the second one.